# Undeterministtic behavior in Fortran Object oriented with deferred and non_overridable procedures and gcc compiler

Tags: oop, fortran, abstract-class, gfortran

I build the simple case to reproduce the problem below. I could not reduce it further.
Description of the problem:
I have 3 classes

- A, abstract class in the module A_Mod (A_Mod.f90) with the deferred procedure `cleanup`
- B, abstract class extending A, in the module B_Mod (B_Mod.f90). B implements the deferred procedure `cleanup`, defines and implements the procedures: `init, finalize`, and defines the following deferred procedures: `setup, free_resources, reset`;
- C, extending B, in the module C_Mod (C_Mod.f90) and implementing the deferred procedures `setup, free_resources, reset`

a test program (test.f90) that defines a variable (object of type C), call `init` followed by `finalize` procedures on the object.

It appears that the procedure called in the source code is not what is being called (run) in the executable: subroutine calls are messed up at compilation time. A small change (with gfortran 7.5.0) like removing the `non_overridable` on the procedure `init` of the class `B` makes an indefinite loop calling `init` (like if init and setup pointed to the same procedure). This loop behavior can be reproduced by some other small changes in the code.

I suspect that the problem is linked to the `deferred` and `non_overridable`. Unless I am making a mistake, it looks like a bug in gfortran that was introduced after 4.8.5.

Expected output:

```
Test: calling C%init
  B::init, calling setup
    C::setup
  B::init done ...............
Test: calling C%finalize
  B::finalize, calling free_resources
    C::free_resources
  B::finalize, calling cleanup
  B::cleanup
  B::finalize done ...................
Test:done.......................
```

I am getting this instead:

```
Test: calling C%init
  B::init, calling setup
  B::cleanup
  B::init done ...............
Test: calling C%finalize
  B::finalize, calling free_resources
    C::setup
  B::finalize, calling cleanup
  B::cleanup
  B::finalize done ...................
Test:done.......................
```

I tried with the following version of gfortran:

- ifort 19.0.5.281 => expected result
- ifort 19.0.4.243 => expected result
- ifort 19.0.2.187 => expected result
- ifort 18.0.1     => expected result
- ifort 17.0.4     => expected result
- GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.8.5 => expected result
- GNU Fortran (GCC) 6.3.0 => wrong result (a little different from other, see below)
- GNU Fortran (GCC) 7.5.0 => wrong result
- GNU Fortran (GCC) 8.4.0 => wrong result
- GNU Fortran (GCC) 9.2.0 => wrong result
- GNU Fortran (GCC) 8.2.0 => wrong result
- GNU Fortran (GCC) 7.3.0 => wrong result

Result with gfortran 6 (see call to reset)

```
Test: calling C%init
  B::init, calling setup
  B::cleanup
  B::init done ...............
Test: calling C%finalize
  B::finalize, calling free_resources
    C::reset
  B::finalize, calling cleanup
  B::cleanup
  B::finalize done ...................
Test:done.......................
```

Source code:

```
$ cat A_Mod.f90
```

```
    !
    module A_Mod
    implicit none
        !
        private
        !
        type, public, abstract :: A
            private
            logical :: status !< status of the object
        contains
            !   
            procedure, non_overridable :: setStatus
            procedure :: unsetStatus
            !
            procedure( cleanup ), deferred :: cleanup
            !procedure, nopass :: do_nothing
        end type A
        !
        interface cleanup
            !
            subroutine cleanup(this)
                import A
                class(A), intent(in out) :: this
            end subroutine cleanup
        end interface cleanup
        !
    contains
        !
        subroutine setStatus(this)
            class(A), intent(in out) :: this
            !
            this%status = .true.
        end subroutine setStatus
        !
        subroutine unsetStatus(this)
            class(A), intent(in out) :: this
            !
            this%status = .false.
        end subroutine unsetStatus
    !     !
    !     subroutine do_nothing()
    !     end subroutine do_nothing
        !
    end module A_Mod
```

```
cat B_Mod.f90
```

```
!
    module B_Mod
        !
        use A_Mod
    implicit none
        !
        private
        integer, private, parameter :: version = 0
        !
        type, public, abstract, extends(A) :: B
            integer :: action
        contains
            !
            procedure (free_resources), deferred :: free_resources
            procedure (reset), deferred :: reset
            procedure (setup), deferred :: setup
            !
            procedure, non_overridable :: init
            !
            ! Procedures from A
            procedure, non_overridable :: finalize
            procedure, non_overridable :: cleanup
            !
        end type B
        !
        interface
            !
            subroutine free_resources( this )
                import B
                class(B), intent(in out) :: this
                !
            end subroutine free_resources
            !
            subroutine reset( this )
                import B
                class( B ), intent(in out) :: this
            end subroutine reset
            !
            subroutine setup( this )
                import B
                class(B), intent(in out) :: this
                !
            end subroutine setup
            !
        end interface
        !
    contains
        !
        subroutine init( this )
            class(B), intent(in out) :: this
            !
            write(*,"('  B::init, calling setup')")
            call this%setup()
            write(*,"('  B::init done ...............')")
            this%action=1
            !
        end subroutine init
        !
        subroutine finalize( this )
            class(B), intent(in out) :: this
            !
            write(*,"('  B::finalize, calling free_resources')")
            call this%free_resources(  )
            write(*,"('  B::finalize, calling cleanup')")
            call this%cleanup()
            write(*,"('  B::finalize done ...................')")
            this%action=0
            !
        end subroutine finalize
        !
        subroutine cleanup( this )
            class(B), intent(in out) :: this
            !
            !call this%do_nothing()
            write(*,"('  B::cleanup')")
            !call this%reset()
            this%action=-1
            !
        end subroutine cleanup
        !
    end module B_Mod
```

```
$ cat C_Mod.f90
```

```
!
module C_Mod
    !
    use B_Mod
    !
implicit none
    !
    private
    !
    type, public, extends(B) :: C
        !integer :: n
    contains
        ! From B
        procedure :: free_resources
        procedure :: reset
        procedure :: setup
        !
    end type C
    !
contains
    !
    subroutine setup( this )
        class(C), intent(in out) :: this
        !
        !call this%do_nothing()
        write(*,"('    C::setup')")
        !
    end subroutine setup
    !
    subroutine free_resources( this )
        class(C), intent(in out) :: this
        !
        !call this%do_nothing()
        write(*,"('    C::free_resources')")
        !
    end subroutine free_resources
    !
    subroutine reset(this)
        class(C), intent(in out) :: this
        !
        !call this%do_nothing()
        write(*,"('    C::reset')")
        !
    end subroutine reset
    !
end module C_Mod
```

```
$ cat test.f90
```

```
!> @file test.f90
!! to test the basic functionalities of the framework
!<

!> @brief test program
!!
!<
program test
    use C_Mod
implicit none
    !
    !
    call test_grid1d()
    !
contains
    !
    subroutine test_grid1d()
        type(C) :: c1
        !
        write(*,"('Test: calling C%init')")
        call c1%init()
        write(*,"('Test: calling C%finalize')")
        call c1%finalize()
        write(*,"('Test:done.......................')")
        !
    end subroutine test_grid1d
    !
end program test
```

Compiled and run as

```
COMPILE=gfortran -g
LINK=gfortran
${COMPILE} A_Mod.f90 -o A_Mod.o
${COMPILE} B_Mod.f90 -o B_Mod.o
${COMPILE} C_Mod.f90 -o C_Mod.o
${COMPILE} test.f90  -o test.o

${LINK} -o  test A_Mod.o  B_Mod.o C_Mod.o test.o
./test
```

Comment: I presume the question is "Is this a compiler bug"?

Comment: @IanH, looks to me like a compiler bug!

Comment: So, are you going to report the bug to the developers?

Comment: I just reported: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94660

Answer (score 2):

This appears to a bug in current gfortran (9.3).  It requires quite specific circumstances, including having the source for the modules in separate files.

If you want the bug addressed, it is best to report through the normal gcc bug reporting channels (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/).

Comment: It's a bug since version 6.3.0, possibly before that. 4.8.5 produces the expected result.